# Reading an environment variable from the remote host

Tags: ansible

I'm attempting to write an Ansible task that utilizes an environment variable on the remote host.

Based on the docs I've thought to use either `lookup('env', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK') or`ansible_env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK` but neither is returning the correct value. If I use the former it returns the value from my local host (not the remote host). If I use the latter is returns nothing.

If I ssh into the machine I'm able to run `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` without issue.

My understanding was that `ansible_env` was the proper access point for remote host environment variables but that seems to not be the case.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible the env variable (SSH_AUTH_SOCK) is not in the remote's env, so it is returning nothing. One way to rule this out is to get something that is always available, eg: `USER` or `SSH_CLIENT`. If you can get that value, then you can safely assume SSH_AUTH_SOCK is not set in remote's env.

```
  - debug: msg={{ ansible_env.USER }}
```

The reason you see SSH_AUTH_SOCK is set when you ssh into the machine could be: Your login profile or bash script is starting `ssh-agent` which sets SSH_AUTH_SOCK variable with the unix socket so that `ssh-add` works correctly.